# Python: Formatting lists of lists

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm a newbie to Python. I have the code below which basically extracts some 5 rows from a MySql table.

```
  if keyword.lower() == 'last5':
            cursor.execute('SELECT income_Ref, income_Amount FROM model_income WHERE company_MobileNumber = %s ORDER BY income_Datetime DESC LIMIT 5', [sender])
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            result = [list(row) for row in result]
            self.respond(result)
            return ()
```

The self.respond() kinda works like print() but it sends a text message instead.I am having trouble formatting the output. What I get from the code above is a list of lists which looks likes this:

> [[u'2014-11-06fd753b-inc', u'50.0'], [u'2014-11-067d724b-inc', u'50.0'], [u'2014-11-067557d6-inc', u'50.0']]

I really wish I new how to make it look like this:

```
Ref:2014-11-06fd753b-inc Amount:50.0 
Ref:2014-11-067d724b-inc Amount:50.0
Ref:2014-11-067557d6-inc Amount:50.0
```

That includes prefixing 'Ref' and 'Amount' before each respective field. I swear I have searched high and low on how to do that for a week now but I'm failing to crack it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
self.respond("\n".join("Ref:{} Amount:{}".format(ref, amt) for ref, amt in result))
```

Not really beginner material, but...

Joining a string (created by formatting `"Ref:{} Amount:{}"`) with `"\n"` using a generator

```
if keyword.lower() == 'last5':
    cursor.execute('SELECT income_Ref, income_Amount FROM model_income WHERE company_MobileNumber = %s ORDER BY income_Datetime DESC LIMIT 5', [sender])
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    result = [list(row) for row in result]
    self.respond("\n".join("Ref:{} Amount:{}".format(ref, amt) for ref, amt in result))
    return ()
```

I left the list comprehension `result = [list(row) for row in result]` because I don't know what `fetchall()` actually returns.

Output:

```
Ref:2014-11-06fd753b-inc Amount:50.0
Ref:2014-11-067d724b-inc Amount:50.0
Ref:2014-11-067557d6-inc Amount:50.0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
["Ref:" + i[0][2:-1] + " Amount: " + i[1][2:-1] + "\n" for i in result]
```

Comment: Select this as your chosen answer if it was the most helpful so others can find it.